# Mapping Bazel test action to remote strategy

Tags: bazel

I have a Bazel project with lots of unit tests and where a subset requires GPU support.

I would like to map the unit tests that have GPU requirements to *remote* strategy but keep all other unit tests as *sandboxed*, running locally. Since all tests share the same mnemonic (TestRunner) I am not sure how to do that using the *strategy* or the *strategy_regexp* parameters.

Is this use case supported by Bazel? Or do you have to either map all or no tests to remote execution?

Kind regards!

Comment: Hey @mareld, I have a similar problem of changing the strategy on a per-target basis. Have you eventually figured out a solution?

Comment: No. We had to map everything as for now. However, we would still want a more fine granular solution in the future.

Comment: Just found some solution. I could not get it working with some kind of custom mnemonic, so explored regexp.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem (another flavour though: have some `//some/test/target` run locally while others run as remote/worker/sandboxed) and ended up writing

```
test --strategy=remote,worker,sandboxed  # force sandbox: no local
test --strategy_regexp=//some/test/target=local  # allow local
test --worker_sandboxing=true
test --incompatible_legacy_local_fallback=false
```

unfortunately, this regex can become quite big so consider some clever naming if you have bunch of those "exceptional" tests, e.g. call all of them `_special_tag` and write a regex like

```
test --strategy_regexp=//.*_special_tag=local  # allow local for `*_special_tag
```

What can help to debug is to run

```
bazel aquery //some/test/target 2>/dev/null
```

to understand what actually matches on that regexp.